# In struts2 internationalization in Arabic how to automatically change cursor in textboxes to rtl?

Tags: struts2, internationalization, arabic

I have implemented internationalization in my Struts2 application and it is working fine, but how do I change the cursor position automatically in all the textboxes in all the jsp to RTL when I select Arabic as the language?

If you could give me a simple example it would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you want to show your current selected language in the textbox?

Comment: No, if arabic is selected I want the cursor to move from right to left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding `dir` attribute to the `<html>` tag in JSP-s, using Struts2 `<s:if>` tag to check current locale language:

```
<html <s:if test="locale.language == 'ar'">dir="rtl"</s:if> >
  ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one(*not tested*)

Well its simple. Lets assume that  you are storing the current selected language in session  with name `currlang` . Then on each text-box do

`<s:textfield label="Some Test Box" name="nameit"  cssStyle="<s:if test="#session['currlang'] == 'arbic'">direction: rtl;</s:if>"/>`