# struts2 - components arrangement - right to left languages

Tags: struts2, internationalization, right-to-left

How can I clearly tell to struts2 to right-to-left arrange components and vice-versa, on runtime, when changing language ?

For example : `s:textfield` tag makes the label on the left and input on the right. So I would like to inverse this orientation on runtime when switching to a rtl language.

I tried struts2 simple theme, dir and labelposition attributes without any success.
If there is any way to rearrange all struts2 page components in once, it will be welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14973594/1700321.

Comment: `<s:textfield dir="rtl" ...>` didn't work. Label still on the left.

Comment: Put it in `<html>` tag or in some wrapping element.

Comment: If i put it in an html input, it may not be submitted with the struts2 form ! Is there any struts2 property to fill for this job ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way in struts2 to rearrange label and textfield positioning without using pure HTML ?

Comment: 1. *Rearrange* all or nothing. 2. Do you have `<html>` tag in your JSP? You should. 3. S2 tags will be translated into *pure* HTML.